# how to restore with batch file in windows

Tags: batch-file

I am solving some problems, two of the are backup and restore file with batch file.

I have found out using xcopy command to backup files,

```
xcopy "%programfiles(x86)%\VMware" "C:\Backup" /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y
```

but I still have some problems with the restore the backup files which should restore in a new folder and restore in an existing folder.

I searched on some website, some code use the same xcopy command and changed source/destination directory to restore file. Is there a command for restore or everyone changes their directory to restore files?

Comment: You really should explain what problems you have and how they are related to batch, provide a [mcve].

Comment: The problem is backup a folder in windows using batch file and restore the backup file in a new/existing folder

Comment: Sorry I still don't grep **what** problem **you** have.

Comment: Do you mean you want to roll back, i.e. replace the current thing with the back up created by the script? If so, what's the issue? Why wouldn't `xcopy "C:\Backup" "%programfiles(x86)%\VMware"` work?

Comment: yes, I want to roll back. Just want to would if there is a command for restore like xcpoy is for backup.

Comment: Explain how you do this manually step-by-step. You need to rewrite what you are trying to accomplish and make that more clear. If you do not know how to explain, then write step-by-step exactly what you do to restore from the backup location now? Perhaps you need to `RD` and then `MD` and then XCOPY /F /Y C:\BackupFolder C:\RestoreToFolder\ and be sure to put a backslash after the destination path just as I put in the example. So remove the folder, then create it, and then copy over the files and folders from the backup location. Simple as that otherwise clarify with better writing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use robocopy for that. I have successfully implemented using that. You can use xcopy if you want. During backup you can save the backups inside a folder which is named based on current date and time. You can find last or range of files and folders in the backup directory. Which you need to mirror in the destination directory